# Can anyone think of an algorithm which uses a skip list to search for an element but finds it in O(log(k)) where k is the elements index?

Tags: algorithm, search, time-complexity, skip-lists

As described above. I'm trying to think of an algorithm to search for an element using a skip list where are the `n` elements. However, instead of finding it in `O(log(n))`, I want to find it in `O(log(k))`, where `k` is the **index** of the desired element.

Any suggestions?

Comment: use hash-map is faster

Comment: not allowed to use hash-maps

Comment: ...........why?

Comment: We were given this question before learning how to use hash-maps and are, therefore, not allowed to use them.

Comment: This is an easy homework problem.  You don't have to start with the top list.

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski I call BS.  A hash map is a **lot** slower than a skip-list for finding the `k`th largest element in the set.  In fact for that purpose a hash map is actually worse than an unordered array because it is more complex to iterate over it!

Comment: consider k as a binary value, for each 1 in it, you will want to skip that. For example 10 is 1010. You start at index 0, skip to 8. Then at 8 you skip 2 places, going to 10.